# Last index can't be located

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a very different problem here.

I have this code

```
xpath = "//div[@class='z-listheader-content'][normalize-space()='Name']/ancestor::table/../following-sibling::div/table"
array = @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).rows.map { |row| [row.cells[0], row.cells[0].text] }
col = array.filter_map { |x| x if x[1].eql?(result) }
```

When I am executing the aforementioned code, it throws the following error

```
timed out after 10 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Row: located: false; {:xpath=>\"//div[@class='z-listheader-content'][normalize-space()='Name']/ancestor::table/../following-sibling::div/table\", :visible=>true, :tag_name=>\"table\"} --> {:index=>10}> to be located\""
```

10 is actually the last index of the table.

But it works fine if I put sleep 5 before my code segment. However, I was expecting WATIR to be automatically waited, but this is not the case, May I know why?

Here is more clear explanation

I am printing this line

```
p @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).rows.count
```

With sleep this is printing `10`

without sleep, this is throwing the following error ends with `{:index=>11}> to be located\`, you could see the full error below

```
"timed out after 10 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Row: located: false; {:xpath=>\"//div[@class='z-listheader-content'][normalize-space()='Name']/ancestor::table/../following-sibling::div/table\", :visible=>true, :tag_name=>\"table\"} --> {:index=>11}> to be located\""
```

Comment: quick question.  how is `@browser` set up?

Comment: @Jad It was initialized with @browser=WATIR::Browser.new

Comment: @engineersmnky No, that was the case for older version of WATIR but now we don't have to use wait_until, it's automatic.

Comment: I am very much aware of what you are talking. I am using WATIR every single day. But my problem above is quite different.

Comment: @Rajagopalan - Is there some JavaScript behaviour around the table (eg auto-loading rows, etc)? Seems weird that the iterator would be locating something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @JustinKo that's why it confuses me. I have been trying various ways since morning, nothng seems to be worked out. Even I am trying to print this line `p @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).rows.count` but this also throws the following error `"timed out after 10 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Row: located: false; {:xpath=>\"//div[@class='z-listheader-content'][normalize-space()='Name']/ancestor::table/../following-sibling::div/table\", :visible=>true, :tag_name=>\"table\"} --> {:index=>11}> to be located\""`

Comment: @Rajagopalan - `#rows` does some extra logic around nested tables. Do you get the same problem if you use `#trs` instead?

Comment: @JustinKo yes, I tried with this `@browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).trs.count` same problem happens. `timed out after 10 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Row: located: false; {:xpath=>\"//div[@class='z-listheader-content'][normalize-space()='Name']/ancestor::table/../following-sibling::div/table\", :visible=>true, :tag_name=>\"table\"} --> {:index=>10}> to be located`

Comment: @JustinKo ......but if I give sleep 3 before  `p @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).trs.count` it's printing properly.

Comment: Are you sure you ran the `#trs` code correctly? That error message is still referring to `Watir::Row` but I would have expected it to refer to `Watir::TableRow`.

Comment: Oh okay, I see! But how would take column value now? Like how would I write equivalent code of `b.table.rows {|row| row.cells[0].text}` Is there anyway to achieve the same using tr?

Comment: @JustinKo hi, Here is the error message `"timed out after 10 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TableRow: located: false; {:xpath=>\"//div[@class='z-listheader-content'][normalize-space()='Name']/ancestor::table/../following-sibling::div/table\", :visible=>true, :tag_name=>\"table\"} --> {:tag_name=>\"tr\", :index=>10}> to be located\""` when I use `p @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).trs.map {|tr| tr.text}`

Comment: If there are no nested tables then `b.table.trs { |tr| tr.td.text }` or `b.table.trs { |tr| tr.tds[0].text }` would be equivalent. Should be more performant too.

Comment: Can you try seeing if you're getting a different table before and after sleeping? Try checking if the same table element is matched `p @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).wd.ref; sleep(5); p @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).wd.ref`. Then also try seeing if the HTML of the table is changing - `p @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).html; sleep(5); p @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).html`.

Comment: @JustinKo I did as you told me, yes, it changes the reference, it's printing `[:element, "c8512ad4-981c-4931-8c88-1f42ad4c5b09"]
[:element, "35a1791d-fc51-4a87-be73-7898946084f7"]`

Comment: If the table is changing, that might explain why Watir is not finding the right rows. That would not be something Watir would know to wait for. You need to either use a better locator (so that it doesn't return different tables) or add in a wait (as @engineersmnky mentioned).

Comment: @JustinKo Hi Justin, I have solved my problem using your given code `@browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).wd.ref`, Using this code I have written the following code `a = []
        @browser.wait_until do
          @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).click
          a << @browser.table(xpath: xpath, visible: true).wd.ref
          a.uniq.count > 1
        end` It worked! I am clicking the table before(or wait_until(&:present) it takes the reference because once we use `wd` we are losing our watir wait.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Documentation](http://watir.com/guides/waiting/) on waiting there are a few key points that should be noted:

> The idea behind implicit waits is good, but there are two main issues with this form of implementation, so Watir does not recommend and does not provide direct access for setting them.
>
> - The wait happens during the locate instead of when trying to act on the element. This makes it impossible to immediately query the state of an element before it is there.
> - Implicit waits by themselves will not be sufficient to handle all of the synchronization issues in your code. The combination of delegating waiting responsibilities to the driver and leveraging polling in the code (explicit waits) can cause weirdness that is difficult to debug...

> ...The second and recommended approach to waiting in Selenium is to use explicit waits...

> ...Note that Watir does its automatic waiting when taking actions, not when attempting to locate...

In your case the wait is needed for location and thus the "automatic" wait you were expecting is not actually how `watir` works.

The Watir library does however provide mechanisms for explicit waits:

- [`wait_until`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Waitable#wait_until-instance_method)  which waits until a specific condition is true
- [`wait`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Browser#wait-instance_method) Waits until readyState of document is complete.

It appears that based on your posted issue that a waiting timeout has expired for your location before the element could be found.

It is possible that `wait_until` would resolve this e.g.

```
table = @browser.table(xpath: xpath).wait_until(&:visible?)
puts table.rows.count
```

Comment: I am saying you don't have to do this, because wait_until is automatic now. If it's text_field, watir automatically waits for exists, visible, enabled, writable, If it's button, watir waits for exists, visible, enabled. default_timeout will be used for this purpose.

Comment: @Rajagopalan yes if it is a `text_field` or a `button` and you are performing an action on it you are correct (which is also very much discussed in the docs); however you are locating a table and its rows in which case there is no automatic wait per the documentation. Your issue is very clearly bullet point #1 *"The wait happens during the locate instead of when trying to act on the element."*